# Таймаут на выполнение хука beforeEach в Mocha.js

Tags: javascript, mocha

В ряде случаев, установка тестового окружения в хуках вроде `beforeEach` может занимать существенное время. Например, вот такой тестовый сценарий

```
describe('case', function() {
    beforeEach(function(done) {
        setTimeout(done, 2500);
    });

    it('should do something', function(done) {
        // ...
        setTimeout(done, 100);
    });
});
```

Завершается с ошибкой

> 1) case "before each" hook for "should do something":
>        Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.

Очевидно, что проблема не в тесте `"should do something"` а в хуке `beforeEach`.

Официальная [документация](https://mochajs.org/#timeouts) говорит, что можно задавать таймауты для тестовых случаев/кейсах (`it`/`describe`). Но это не совсем верный путь, поскольку ограничение времени на тестовые сценарии должно оставаться прежним.

Возможно ли установить отдельный таймаут для хука, но так, чтобы таймаут для тестовых случаев и кейсов (блоки `it` и `describe`) оставался прежним?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несмотря на то, что документация (уж не знаю почему) не упоминает этого факта, вы можете задавать таймаут и для отдельных хуков. Вот так:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
    this.timeout(3000);
    setTimeout(done, 2500);
});
```

**UPD:**

Совсем недавно официальная документация обновилась и в ней полностью отражен пример, приведенный мной ранее.